# Best way to get hostname with php

Tags: php

I have a php application that is installed on several servers and all of our developers laptops.  I need a fast and reliable way to get the server's hostname or some other unique and reliable system identifier.  Here's what we have thought of so far:

`<? $hostname = (!empty($_ENV["HOSTNAME"])) ? $_ENV["HOSTNAME"] : env('HOSTNAME'); ?>`

`<? $hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']); ?>`

`<? $hostname = exec('hostname'); ?>`

What do you think?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

What about [gethostname()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php)?

Edit:  This might not be an option I suppose, depending on your environment.  It's new in PHP 5.3.  [php_uname('n')](http://php.net/php_uname) might work as an alternative.

Comment: `php_uname('n')` does not always equal `$_SERVER['HOST_NAME']`

The machine that you are running the script may server many different host names so don't use this when building urls.

Comment: Aren't hostnames unique to each machine on the same domain? As I understand this, a single machine ( or server ) would only have one hostname, because you cannot have for example two machines called iamaserver on the *same domain* ( iamaserver.somedomain.tld ). The only case where I can see where this is not true is if PHP is running as CGI on a separate machine from the web server.

Answer (score 44):

For [PHP >= 5.3.0 use this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php):

`$hostname = gethostname();`

For [PHP < 5.3.0 but >= 4.2.0 use this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php):

`$hostname = php_uname('n');`

For PHP < 4.2.0 use this:

```
$hostname = getenv('HOSTNAME'); 
if(!$hostname) $hostname = trim(`hostname`); 
if(!$hostname) $hostname = exec('echo $HOSTNAME');
if(!$hostname) $hostname = preg_replace('#^\w+\s+(\w+).*$#', '$1', exec('uname -a'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use...

```
$hostname = getenv('HTTP_HOST');
```

Comment: Note that this is insecure; `HTTP_HOST` is controlled by the client, not the server, so relying on it is dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

I am running PHP version 5.4 on shared hosting and both of these both successfully return the same results:

```
php_uname('n');

gethostname();
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer of `gethostname()` may, in fact, give you an inaccurate value as it does in my case:

```
gethostname()         = my-macbook-pro     (which is my machine name)
$_SERVER['host_name'] = mysite.git         (which is my website name)
```

The value from `gethostname()` is obviously wrong. Be careful with it.

Comment: "The value from gethostname() is obvsiously wrong." - `gethostname()` returns the "local machine name", so in your case that actually looks about right? `mysite.git` looks like the `HTTP_HOST`. (`$_SERVER['host_name']` is not normally set.)

Comment: @MrWhite `$_SERVER['host_name']` = `null`, `getenv('HTTP_HOST')` = `bool(false)`, `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`= `localhost:port` which finally did it and wiw = what i want.

Answer (score 1):

[php_uname](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php) but I am not sure what hostname you want the hostname of the client or server.

plus you should use cookie based approach

Comment: need to hostname of the server, not the client.

Comment: php_uname should make it, are you sure those hostname won't have any duplicate ?

Answer (score 0):

Whether your webserver is Apache, NGINX or otherwise; you can set the headers which are forwarded to your PHP application. While slightly safer on its own, due to browser behavior, the [Origin header](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/http-headers-origin/) is useful for this scenario.

For example, with NGINX:
Add an explicit set to `fastcgi_param HTTP_ORIGIN` either as a hard-coded string, based on $server_name or $ssl_server_name. This is done in an NGINX server block context which will ensure host strings matched with the header, but you don't pass the header directly to your app. Apache configs have the same information available in the virtual host configs.

This way, the string going to your app is predefined by your project. The main point is that user submitted headers will be checked against accepted values -- but never passed along. The existing accepted value will be passed along instead.