# How to read the host name from a request URI in PHP?

Tags: php, httprequest, uri, psr-7

For the router, I wanted to get the host name from the URI upon a server request. I know that I need to read it from the `$_SERVER` variable. But it seems that in the `$_SERVER` array there are multiple entries (at least two) for the host name.

Could you please tell me which value should I choose to read - the most reliable one?

For example, when I have an URI like this:

```
http://local.mvc/mycontroller/myaction
```

the `$_SERVER` array will have:

```
[HTTP_HOST] => local.mvc
[SERVER_NAME] => local.mvc
```

I need to obtain the value `local.mvc`.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you choose to downvote my question, could you please motivate the choice, so that I can reedit my question and make it better? In this way all of us will benefit from a good question, good answers and a better website. Thank you.

Comment: You can use any of the above array key to get host name. Both are reliable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to get hostname with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408996/best-way-to-get-hostname-with-php)

Comment: Thank you, @PratikGadoya. In the docs I saw that there are "structural" differences between the two values and that SERVER_NAME, in a not properly configured virtual host, can be spoofed.

Comment: Hello @AZinkey and thank you for the comment. I would like to ask you to remove the "duplicate" status of my question, because in my question I'm referring myself to the case of a website host name and all answers in your proposed link are referring to a function to read the machine name and/or to a server variable which is not anymore actual. I reedited my question to better reflect what I want to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SERVER_NAME` is the name assigned to the given server in its configuration (be it i.e. `apache.conf` file and its `ServerName` directive or similar for other software), while `HTTP_HOST` value is obtained from the [headers of HTTP request](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23) that comes from client (web browser usually). These two **might** differ if your server servers multiple domains (like shared server / virtual server hosting). Depending on the use case you may want to use either of these, however `HTTP_HOST` seems like better choice as it is always tells what user wanted to reach.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm not sure what you exactly mean. Could you please extend a bit, eventually with a simple example? I would be very grateful. I have my perspective on what you say, but I may be wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what is unclear in my answer, but I edited it slightly. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi again and sorry for the delay... The multiple virtual hosts situation was unclear for me. I couldn't "imagine" it myself. But now I do. Thank you for reediting your answer!

Answer (score 0):

the `$_SERVER` variable has `'REQUEST_URI'`.

just `var_dump` the server variable, and is should be there (or look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php))

Comment: Thank you, SmartCoder. In the `REQUEST_URI` item I have only the URI path, e.g. `/mycontroller/myaction`.

Comment: in that case `HTTP_HOST` is what you want

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP5 or PHP7, try [php_uname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php)

To get the host name:

```
php_uname("n");
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I tried it and is not what I want. The `php_uname('n')` function returns the host name of the machine, not of the request URI as sent from a browser. And `php_uname()` in general _returns information about the operating system PHP is running on_.