# How to get the name of the host in PHP?

Tags: php

this is what i have tried:

```
header('location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/HTML-CW/Account.html');
```

i also tried this

```
$hostDb = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
header('location: http://"$hostDb"/HTML-CW/Account.html');
```

Comment: try `header('location: http://' .$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/HTML-CW/Account.html');`. Notice the use of single quotes instead of double. You can use either BUT, consistently across the statement.

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408996/best-way-to-get-hostname-with-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to get hostname with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408996/best-way-to-get-hostname-with-php)

Answer (score -1):

gethostname — Gets the host name https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] Returns the name of the host server (such as www.google.com)

$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] Returns the Host header from the current request

http://www.google.com
HTTP_HOST = www.google.com
SERVER_NAME = google.com

http://172.217.31.206
HTTP_HOST = 172.217.31.206
SERVER_NAME = google.com
```

SERVER_NAME is determined by server configuration;
HTTP_HOST is tied to the request

header('location: http://' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . '/HTML-CW/Account.html');

or

header('location: http://' . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . '/HTML-CW/Account.html');

would solve your problem. See " is converted to '.

Also do echo($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]) and echo($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]) to see what it is outputting in your environment.